# Java - If statement A is equal to B plus or minus 2

Tags: java, if-statement

I've got a problem that seems easy to solve, however I'm not sure on the syntax.

I need to have an if/else statement run, but I'm not sure on how to set the conditions correctly.

Bad code:

```
if (float_a = float_b or is within +-2 of it) {
    do this
}
else {
    do that
}
```

What's the simplest way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Take a hard look at the `<=` and `>=` operators. Of course, with floats, rounding may or may not be a problem here for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Math.abs`:

```
if (Math.abs(float_a-float_b) <= 2) { ... }
```

This means *"if the absolute difference between a and b is within 2..."*.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! When the timer ends I'll toss the accepted answer over to you.

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

```
if(Math.abs(float_a - float_b) <= 2) {
    //do this
}
else {
    //do that
}
```